# Regex: Any word and numeric combination but with a single underscore

Tags: regex

I would like to match a whole string if it contains letters or numbers or a *single underscore sequence*, so:

Accepted:

- H_i_there
- _this_is_OK_
- _x_y_5_z
- abddd_cdxxx

Not accepted:

- s___2
- __s__t__2
- __x____x4

So multiple, consecutive underscores are not allowed. How does the regex expression look for this? My version is: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\_{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\_{0,1}$`, but this must be recursive, somehow, for it to work, and AFAIK, regex does not support such complicated functionality.

Comment: When I need to count for specific chars in patterns, I prefer to avoid regex. What tool are you using? This can be easily done using almost any language.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree, but regex is much cleaner, and if it can do it for me, then perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xw2VXB/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `_?` - an optional `_`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `_` - 1 underscore
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `_?` - an optional `_`
- `$` -  end of string

A less efficient, but shorter pattern:

```
^(?:_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zqCBRx/1).

Comment: FYI, you do not want a *recursive* regex here, just a *repetitive* pattern, and a "repeated" non-capturing group (`(?:...)*`) is quite handy here. If you want  a `_` to appear at least one time, you may add a positive lookahead: `^(?=[^_]*_)_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?$`

Comment: No need for the beginning: `^(?:_?[a-zA-Z0-9])+_?$` works exactly the same

Comment: you mean as Wiktor wrote in 2nd regex?

Comment: @Christoph: No, not the same, there is much more backtracking involved. I mentioned it by saying the second regex is less efficient. It is not a good idea to quantify optional grouped patterns, though people usually love shorter patterns. In vain: a shorter regex does not always mean a more efficient regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if you go for performance don't use a backtracking regex implementation in first place.

Comment: There's something wrong about this. "t0" is rejected! Why?

Comment: [`t0`](https://regex101.com/r/LnehK4/1) is not "rejected", it is *matched*. It is also [matched with the first regex](https://regex101.com/r/LnehK4/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry. It's my fault. Can I add one more condition? What should I do if I want the first character to be non-numeric?

Comment: You may use `^(?![0-9])_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?$` (or `^(?![0-9])(?:_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?$`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to disallow `__`

```
^(?!.*?__)\w+$
```

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/NTv80a/1)

`\w` matches a *word-character* `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (including the underscore).